# How to Convert C# Desktop Application Project to website

Tags: c#

I Created an application in my desktop using c#.

I want to use this application in my website.

Is it Possible or there is any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible unless you rewrite the application for Web. They are totally different things.

Comment: Ok Thanks For your reply but i cant vote to because i am not having suffecient reputations